# How to keep event listener on textarea after changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a color input field to change a .SVG color, there is a text area where the hex of the selected color is stored. As of now I can either use the color swatch or write the hex in the textarea to change the svg color.

The problem is that if I write the hex code, the event listener stops working and if I use the swatch again, the textarea won't change.

HTML:

```
<div id="inputColor" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>Color</span>
    <textarea class="form-control mb-1 d-inline-block ml-3 mr-3" rows="1" maxlength='7'></textarea>
    <input type="color" name="head" style="margin-bottom:4px;">
</div>
```

JS:

```
inputColorPicker.addEventListener('input', () => {
    inputColor.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML = inputColorPicker.value;
    changeSVGColor(inputColorPicker.value);
});

inputColor.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input', () => {
    inputColorPicker.value = inputColor.querySelector('textarea').value;
    changeSVGColor(inputColorPicker.value);
});

function changeSVGColor(hex) {
    mySVG.style.fill = hex;
}
```

How can I make it so the event listeners won't stop working?

Comment: You should assign to the `.value` of the textarea, not `.innerHTML`

Comment: ^ Do that. Or, you could attach the event listener to the parent element, and then changing the HTML of the child element wouldn't matter.